# Two Fragment open in a fragment

Tags: java, android

I am facing a problem of overlapping fragments when i clock Forget password textview than ResetPasswordFragment is coming but RegisterActivity fragment or Company logo is also coming.
ResetPasswordFragment is onViewCreated in SignInFragment. plz help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVbGD.jpg)

public class ResetPasswordFragment extends Fragment {

```
public ResetPasswordFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private EditText registeredEmail;
private Button resetPasswordBtn;
private TextView goBack;

private FrameLayout parentFrameLayout;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reset_password, container, false);

    registeredEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.forgot_password_email);
    resetPasswordBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.reset_password_btn);
    goBack = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_forgot_password_go_back);

    parentFrameLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.register_framelayout);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    return view;
}
```

//------------------------

public class SignInFragment extends Fragment {

```
public SignInFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private TextView no_have_an_account;
private FrameLayout parentFrameLayout;

private EditText email;
private EditText password;

private TextView forgotPassword;

private ProgressBar progressBar;

private ImageButton closeBtn;
private Button signInBtn;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

private String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+";


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_in, container, false);

    parentFrameLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.register_framelayout);

    no_have_an_account = view.findViewById(R.id.no_account);

    forgotPassword = view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_forgot_password);

    email = view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_email);
    password = view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_password);

    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_progressbar);

    closeBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_close_btn);
    signInBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_btn);

    firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth.getInstance();



    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, saveInstanceState);

    no_have_an_account.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setFragment(new SignUpFragment());
        }

    } ) ;

    forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setFragment(new ResetPasswordFragment());

        }
    });

    closeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mainIntent();

        }
    });

    email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            checkInputs();

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    password.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            checkInputs();

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    signInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkEmailAndPassword();

        }
    });
}
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_from_right,R.anim.slideout_from_left);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(parentFrameLayout.getId() ,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit() ;

}

private void checkInputs() {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText())){
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText())){
            signInBtn.setEnabled(true);
            signInBtn.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));

        }else {
            signInBtn.setEnabled(false);
            signInBtn.setTextColor(Color.argb(50,255,255,255));

        }

        }else {
        signInBtn.setEnabled(false);
        signInBtn.setTextColor(Color.argb(50,255,255,255));

    }
}

private void checkEmailAndPassword(){
    if (email.getText().toString().matches(emailPattern)){
        if (password.length() >= 8){

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            signInBtn.setEnabled(false);
            signInBtn.setTextColor(Color.argb(50,255,255,255));

            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString())
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                mainIntent();


                            }else {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                signInBtn.setEnabled(true);
                                signInBtn.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                                String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }
                        }
                    }) ;



            }else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Incorrect email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Incorrect email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
private void mainIntent(){
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    getActivity().finish();

}
```

}

Comment: What is "RegisterActivity fragment"? when it init and show?

Comment: RegisterActivity fragment is 1st page with company logo.

Comment: brother error is solved. changing background color of ResetPassword XML .